# Send email with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, email

Hello I am trying to create a method to send emails through my qt app and it works very much ok but when I try to send arabic on non english message it send as "????" question marks 
here is my code

```
    void Smtp::sendMail(const QString &from, const QString &to, const QString &subject, const QString &body)
{
    message.append("User-Agent: Mozilla Thunderbird 1.0.6 (Macintosh/20050716)\n");
    message.append("X-Accept-Language: ar_EG, en_US\n");
    message.append("MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n");
    message = "To: " + to + "\r\n";
    message.append("From: " + from + "\r\n");
    message.append("Subject: " + subject + "\r\n");
    //message.append("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF8;\r\n");
    message.append("Message From Smart Clinic\r\n");
    message.append(QString("Build Number: %1 \r\n").arg(BUILD));
    message.append(QString("Version     : %1 \r\n").arg(APPVERSION));
    message.append(body);
    message.replace( QString::fromLatin1( "\n" ), QString::fromLatin1( "\r\n" ) );
    message.replace( QString::fromLatin1( "\r\n.\r\n" ),QString::fromLatin1( "\r\n..\r\n" ) );

    this->from = from;
    rcpt = to;
    state = Init;
    socket->connectToHostEncrypted(host, port); //"smtp.gmail.com" and 465 for gmail TLS
    if (!socket->waitForConnected(timeout)) {
        emit status( tr( "Failed to send message" ) );
     }

    t = new QTextStream( socket );
}
```

how to make it able to send english and non english text 
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your message is converted in 8-bits array as   ASCII (like Latin1). You should use UTF8 encoding.
Your code looks like incomplete one - some of variable without declaration. So it's hard to say where exactly message converting to bytes

Answer (score 0):

uncomment the below line in your code and try.

```
//message.append("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF8;\r\n");
```

if not try to use the charset type "ISO_8859-7:1987" and check if it is working,

```
message.append("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO_8859-7:1987;\r\n");
```

For more character sets refer

http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

fixed by setting 
"Content-Type: text/plain;
and 
setting codec in 
QTextStream t ;
t.setcodec("UTF-8"");